# несколько кнопок в строку с выравниванием ширины

Tags: android, android-layout

Как расположить несколько кнопок в строку, чтобы ширина всех кнопок была одинакова и было полностью заполнено свобоное пространство?

пробовал TableLayout - кнопки разной ширины

LinearLayout - кнопки разной ширины и не полностью заполнено пространство.

Минимальный api 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `LinearLayout`, каждой кнопке задайте одинаковое значение ширины (сам в таких случаях ставлю 0dp) и `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Кнопки будут одинаковые. При необходимости можете подстраивать пропорции, изменяя значение `layout_weight`.